# ConnectionRequest Error on all connection after NetBeans plugin update

Tags: java, codenameone

I updated the CodenameOne Plugin for NetBeans and since then every connection produces the error below

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.util.Hashtable
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneImplementation.getCookiesForURL(CodenameOneImplementation.java:3934)
    at com.codename1.io.ConnectionRequest.performOperation(ConnectionRequest.java:308)
    at com.codename1.io.NetworkManager$NetworkThread.run(NetworkManager.java:263)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)

Connection for push notifications registration even produces this error.
Any help?

Comment: How did you declare and use the ConnectionRequests that are throwing these exceptions? Provide the full StackTrace

Comment: I was rather doing rogue coding. So rogue that the stack trace which was showing was the only ones above. I went into com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneImplementation.getCookiesForURL sources to realize what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The issue came in because I stored, deleted and restored "Cookies" storage object in some of my ConnectionRequest calls. I should have just set ConnectionRequest's setCookiesEnabled method to false.

Bad code used

```
    try {
          ConnectionRequest connectionRequest = new ConnectionRequest() {

            @Override
            protected void initConnection(Object connection) {
                super.initConnection(connection);
                storeAndDeleteUserCookiesData();
            }

            @Override
            protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {
            }

            @Override
            protected void postResponse() {
                restoreCookies();
            }

            @Override
            protected void handleException(Exception err) {
                restoreCookies();
            }

            @Override
            protected void handleErrorResponseCode(int code, String message) {
                restoreCookies();
            }

            @Override
            public void retry() {
                super.retry();
            }
        };

        NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(connectionRequest);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        restoreCookies();
    }



protected void storeAndDeleteUserCookiesData() {
    if (Storage.getInstance().exists("Cookies")) {
        Storage.getInstance().writeObject("Cookies_" + appName, Storage.getInstance().exists("Cookies"));
        Storage.getInstance().deleteStorageFile("Cookies");
    }
    Storage.getInstance().clearCache();
}

protected void restoreCookies() {
    Storage.getInstance().writeObject("Cookies", Storage.getInstance().readObject("Cookies_" + appName));
    Storage.getInstance().clearCache();
}
```

The fix was

```
        ConnectionRequest connectionRequest = new ConnectionRequest() {
        };
        connectionRequest.setCookiesEnabled(false);
```